# Missing Wordpress WYSIWYG formatting tools

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg

I am trying my hand at developing a Wordpress theme, however I seem to have hit a little snag. When creating posts in Wordpress you have the WYSIWYG content area.

At present, mine looks like this:

[Missing some formatting tools http://www.threethinkers.co.uk/stackoverflow/missing.jpg](http://www.threethinkers.co.uk/stackoverflow/missing.jpg).

However, I would like to make available the following additional formatting tools:

[Missing some formatting tools http://www.threethinkers.co.uk/stackoverflow/not.missing.jpg](http://www.threethinkers.co.uk/stackoverflow/not.missing.jpg).

Does anybody know if this a plugin or do I need to enable something inside Wordpress?

Although I usually get on great with Google, I don't think I am using the correct search terms as the results tend to be off track.

Any help is appreciated - but my preference would be a way of implementing this myself rather than using a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the kitchen sink, which can be expanded by clicking the first button on the right in the first picture.

Comment: +1 - Hmmm, well thats embarrassing. I had pressed that a couple of times and nothing happened. Oh to be shamed on Stack Overflow ;) Thanks for the answer!